# MySQLCommand ExecuteReader Row size too large, query works fine at CLI

Tags: mysql, .net

Our Database Server is running MySQL 5.6.40 on RedHat 6.10

Our Web Server running Windows 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5.X

We recently noticed that when connecting to our database from a .NET form and running a large SQL insert statement, our code throws an exception:

```
Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Yes, the query that is failing is a large query and the size of the text in the query is over 8K, but the weird part is that running the same exact query against the table in question from the MySQL CLI, yields a successful insert. If it was an issue with the row size, it should fail there as well right?

I am wondering if anyone has seen this issue. The only thing I can think of at this point is a bug with the MySQL .NET dlls? From the code, we are referencing an older version of the dlls than what's available, but everything else is working so we are reluctant to install a newer version and have to do a complete re-test of our web site/application. I've read a bunch of the other posts about this error suggesting problems with innoDB page size, configs and such, but if the query works just fine from the CLI, I think that would rule out an error with innoDB.

I am definitely not a DBA, so please be kind.

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help you if you create a [MCVE] in your question. For example, your table definition and the code doing the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Richardissimo, I wish I could. I cannot due to the nature of the system.

We did discover the problem.  I went back to my DBA and the query **was** actually failing from the CLI under the **right conditions**.  As it turns out the problem was related to using the *MySQL CONCAT* to concatenate UTF8 string data into a Latin database:

For example:  UPDATE MYTABLE Set History = CONCAT(History,'new data') WHERE ....

[Failure]

We converted our database to UTF8 and retested and the problem went away.  I still do not totally understand why the database was throwing a "row size too large" error, but at least I know what caused it.

It's also weird that of the millions of SQL transactions that are performed on our Latin database, the queries using CONCAT were the only ones that were problematic.

Comment: I don't know if Oracle has done this in their newer versions of MySQL. If not, Oracle really needs to consider setting UTF8 to be the default format for MySQL.  I think a lot of folks like myself that are web developers use MySQL and know just enough to get MySQL installed and working and don't delve into the intricacies between Latin and UTF8.  Does any Operating System use Latin anymore?